# Returns on time sensitive functions

Tags: jquery, function, if-statement

If I call an if statement as such:

```
if(someRandomFunction()){
    //do stuff
}
```

If the called function returns true but after various invoked delays and timed animations, does this cause the if statement to fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "various invoked delays and timed animations", I presume you are talking about calls to `window.setTimeout()` and such.

When a function registers a delayed event like this, the function continues executing after registering the event, and the event fires later, usually after the registering function has finished executing.

The things that get executed later are also functions.  They can return values, but since those functions are actually called by the browser (when it knows it is time for them to be called), the values get returned to the browser.  In the case of `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` at least, the return value is ignored.

When you call a function, you can (in javascript at least) count on that function to be the one that returns the value to you.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on how the function works, if this always explicitly returns `true` the condition is `true`.

Comment: It always returns true once an each loop is completed. Basically, I only want a certain function to run once the each() completes.

Comment: Yes, this is acting as the callback.

Comment: it depends on the js interpreter, if the function is called when  another calling is not completed yet, sometimes it returns unexpected results, especially when it comes to calculations and floating point numbers.